# Gimp ,, move objects (drag & drop) from work window to another?

Tags: gimp

move objects (drag & drop) from work window to another on GIMP?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: i want to move picture from window to other window (drag and drop )to use it in new window   iam new in gimp & ubuntu

Comment: Are you saying that this does not work (have you tried it?) or that you want to know if it works before you try?